# Recalculate (refresh) and save each outcome to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a R programmer but am attempting VBA for the first time.  I have a pretty simple population projection based on a series of randomly selected birth and survival values. I have predicted population values for years 1 to 20 in cells BC4:BC23 in Sheet1. Every time I refresh, the values change. I would like to refresh 100 times and store each of the population values into Sheet2 (100 columns with 20 values).

Based on my internet searching, it seems that a combination of a loop and `EnableCalculation` is a viable VBA approach for this. I've tried different coding approaches (`Application.EnableEvents`, `CalculateManyTimes`, etc) with no luck. Surely this kind of question has been asked before but I could not find it. Any tips would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Just wondering: so in the end you will have 100+ sheets full of data. How do you want to review / analyse this data? Wouldn't it be better to save all the data in one sheet and then you can put a pivot-table on top? Of course, then you'd have to add an additional column to your data with something like `Calculation00`, `Calculation01`, `Calculation02`, `Calculation03`, etc. Alternatively, you might want to look into SQL Server (if the data amount increases even further) SQL Server 2016 now includes `R`.

Comment: Yes, all simulations would be within 1 sheet (1 column for each simulation for a total of 100 columns). I don't think a column header will be necessary because I'm just going to plot the trends (years 1 to 20).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is `Application.CalculateFull` so the code could be:

```
Sub CalculateAndSave()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Set Ws = Worksheets(2)
    For i = 1 To 100
        Application.CalculateFull
        Ws.Range(Ws.Cells(4, i), Ws.Cells(23, i)) = Sheets(1).Range("BC4:BC23").Value
    Next i
End Sub
```